# congruence equation in number theory

Tags: number-theory

I want to find the natural number $n$ where
$n$ is the multiple of $a^2$, $(n+1)$ is the multiple of $a^3$, $(n+2)$ is the multiple of $a^4$.

I found that $n$ is not even.

CRT is useful, but I can't solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Take $a=1$. Then any natural number $n$ satisfies this. So $n$ can be even.

Comment: Only $a=1$ is possible since $a$ (even $a^2$) is a common factor of consecutive integers $n,n+1(,n+2)$.

Comment: I'd assume you want the opposite $a^2$ is a multiple of $n$ otherwise only $a=1$ is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Assume that $a > 1$ and that prime $p|a$.

Then, $p|n$ and $p|(n+1)$.  This is impossible.

Therefore, $a = 1.$

---

A comment suggested that the problem composer intended that

- $n|a^2$.
- $(n+1)|a^3.$
- $(n+2)|a^4.$

Under this alternative interpretation of the problem, the following approach may be used to construct all possible satisfying pairs $(n,a)$ as follows.

Take a specific value of $n$, for example $n = 7 \times 11$.

Then $(n+1) = 2 \times 3 \times 13$.

And $(n+2) = 79$.

Then, $a$ can be any number whose prime factorization includes $7,11,2,3,13,79.$

You can follow this general approach of starting with any value for $n$, determining the prime factorizations of $n,n+1,n+2$, and then determining what the prime factorization of $a$ must include.

---

To me, the real challenge, that I am deliberately ducking, is to use the alternative interpretation of the problem, and start with a specific value for  $a$, rather than $n$.

Then, the challenge would be to analytically identify all possible values of $n$ that are satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I look at this:

Given that:

1. $a$ and $n$ are natural numbers
2. $a^2 \vert n$
3. $a^3 \vert n + 1$
4. $a^4 \vert n + 2$

Since $a^3 \vert n + 1$, we know that $a^2 \vert n + 1$.

But $a^2 \vert n$, so it must be the case that $a^2 | 1$.

Since $a$ is a natural number, this immediately implies that $a$ must be 1.

At this point one can simplify and say that:

1. $n$ is a natural number
2. $1 \vert n$
3. $1 \vert n + 1$
4. $1 \vert n + 2$

***But (2), (3), and (4) are not restrictions at all, so all we can say is that n is a natural number.***

You can also show that $a^2$ must be 1 as follows:

1. $a$ and $n$ are natural numbers
2. $n = a^2p$, for some integer p
3. $n + 1 = a^3q$, for some integer q
4. $n + 2 = a^4r$, for some integer r

We can proceed as follows:

$n + 1 = a^3q$

$(a^2p) + 1 = a^3q$

$1 = a^3q - a^2p$

$1 = a^2(aq - p)$

So it follows that $a^2 = 1$.